# Use backup restore then attach in Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 migration

Tags: migration, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

The microsoft technet article for using the detach/attach method for migrating from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 is here, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx.

However, I would like to know if it would be possible to not "detach" the original database from Sharepoint 2007 and leave the Sharepoint 2007 system operational. Instead is it possible to do the following procedure?

1. Backup the Sharepoint 2007 DB.
2. Install Sharepoint 2010 on new separate Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008.
3. Restore the DB on separate Windows Server 2008 R2 VM with SQL Server 2008.
4. Attach content database to new Sharepoint 2010 system via powershell commands.

I.e. I want to leave the existing sharepoint site live without having to bring it down and then create a new sharepoint site on a separate system using the same content. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.  That was our process for a recent upgrade to 2010  Be sure to run all pre-upgarde checks and correct any issues before the upgrade. Pay close attention to any added solutions on the 2007 farm.

Comment: +1 Thanks for you answer. By "added solutions", do you mean things like web-parts? There are only some simple custom web parts created within SP 2007. There are no complex coded web-parts..

Answer (score 1):

AS the proposed answer you can do that but it is not advicable to keep the production live as you might lost the data between the backup and making 2010 site live.
1.make 2007 farm readonly from Central admin_contentdatabases_Readonly checked.
2. Backup of Content DB.
3. Attach Content DB via powershell.
4. Update DNS to the new 2010 site.
5.Done!!
http://sharepoint2010blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2010-using.html