# Which Sharepoint 2007 databases do I backup for migration to Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

This is a follow on question from, [Use backup restore then attach in Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 migration](https://serverfault.com/questions/347798/use-backup-restore-then-attach-in-sharepoint-2007-to-2010-migration).

There are 5 databases in the SQL Server Instance for Sharepoint Server 2007:

1. Sharepoint_AdminContent
2. SUSDB
3. WSS_Content_CompanyName_Intranet
4. Sharepoint_Config
5. WSS_Search_WINXXX

Which databases do I backup so that I may restore them on the new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance ready for migration to Sharepoint 2010? In particular what is "SUSDB"? Currently, I have backed up items 1, 2, and 3 and I don't believe I will have to migrate the search and config databases.

Comment: SUSDB is the backend for WSUS

Comment: So do I need to migrate it to 2010 or will it get recreated in 2010 in another shape or form?

Comment: Oh WSUS = Windows Shared Update Services, so I'm guessing no.

Comment: The WSUS db is nothing to do with sharepoint - this server is either also your WSUS server or the SQL backend has been moved to this server. Either way, sharepoint won't create SUSDB, since it's not related.

Comment: So we have knocked off SUSDB, #2, #4 and #5. What about Sharepoint_AdminContent? It seems that will get recreated when the Sharepoint 2010 system is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.SharePoint_AdminContent is for the Central Administration content DB so you don't need backup.
same with 2.4 & 5  you can leave it.
Only back up you need is WSS_Content _Intranet_db
http://sharepoint2010blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2010-using.html
You can check the following series and many more regarding migration.